# CSS not applying to password protected page in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, styles, password-protection

I'm protecting a page with a password and trying to style the password protected page with the login form.

I added a separate CSS class called 'password-protected'.
Everything I add to the stylesheet doesn't apply on the login page. Why isn't the login page loading the same stylesheet like all other pages?
Someone had this issue before?

Answer (score 0):

The function `post_password_required( $post )` requires the post object otherwise, It will be null.
so It should be like that

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'add_password_protected_body_class' );
function add_password_protected_body_class( $classes ) {
  global $post;
  if ( post_password_required( $post ) ) 
    $classes[] = 'password-protected';
  return $classes;
}
```

Comment: This was not was my problem. The function works and shows the class. If you look on the website you will see the class "password-protected". I will remove the code in my post, since it is maybe confusing. Just wanted to say that I added a class to make change on the style.